# Running subgraphs and feeding intermediate variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an autoencoder model in Tensorflow that roughly can be written as (this is unrealistically simplified example):

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, input_shape, name='x')

# encoder part:
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape, -1, 1))
z = relu(tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME'))

# decoder part:
y = relu(tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(z, W, shape_tr, 
         strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME'), b))
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - x))
```

So I have input placeholder `x`, intermediate representation `z`, weights matrix `W` and output `y`.

Then I train my model like this:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: some_train_data})
```

Now given some test data I can check the output of the model:

```
recon = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: some_test_data})
```

I can also get the intermediate representation for that data

```
latent = sess.run(z, feed_dict={x: some_test_data})
```

What I want is to be able to change my intermediate representation (`z`) and obtain the decoded results `y`. Something like this:

```
recon = sess.run(y, feed_dict={z: some_fake_z})
```

Of course, it doesn't work as `z` is not a placeholder, I have an error like `You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x'`. If I provide `x`, the results will not depend on `z` at all (which again is what we can expect).

So my question is: how can I run a subgraph that calculates `y` as a function of `z` and feed it with my own values of `z`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another subgraph with the same variable.

```
fake_z = tf.placeholder(z.dtype, z.name)
fake_y = relu(tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(fake_z, W, shape_tr, 
     strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME'), b))
```

Now you can `sess.run(fake_y, {fake_z: my_values})`.

If you use `tf.layers`, you should also use `variable_scope` to ensure layer weights are the same.

This is one of the limitations of static graph libraries. You have to plan ahead everything you need to calculate.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, I still have to provide some `x` values (which does not have any effect) to make computation work. Is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov: That is surprising to me. Could you link to a complete yet minimal code for me to test? Codes in your question is not runnable, as it has many undefined names like `input_shape`.

Comment: Oh, probably, this is a drawback of my architecture — it seems that decoder part needs some information on shape of `x` and thus depends on the corresponding placeholder.